# Content is not updating until re-deploy nextjs 13 and sanity

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, sanity, next.js13

Hello i am using nextjs 13 server components using /app directory and sanity studio. my code looks like this

```
const Page = async () => {
  const query = groq`*[_type == "university"]`;

  const data = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
}
```

every time i re-deploy my site on vercel, my content loads latest updated data on the frontend.
but if i change something on sanity studio and refresh my page, i only see the old changes.
any help here ? thank you

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you are using Next js 13 app directory. You may try this out

```
const Page = async () => {
  const revalidate = 60 //Time interval
  const query = groq`*[_type == "university"]`;

  const data = await sanityClient.fetch(query, {next: {revalidate}});
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked, however, I don't understand why this is required.

When I remove `{next: {revalidate}}`, it goes back to showing the previous data, not the latest.

Why is it unable to show the latest data without the `revalidate`?

Answer (score 2):

In nextjs 13's app directory you are able to declare a `revalidate` variable like this:

```
// page.tsx

export const Page = async () => {
  const query = groq`*[_type == "university"]`;

  const data = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
}

export const revalidate = 60; // revalidate this page every 60 seconds
```

This causes your page to get invalid after 60 seconds. If you try to open your page after 60 seconds, the pages cache gets cleared and it will be updated.

If you don't want your page to be static at all, insert a `'use client'` in the first line of your `page.tsx;`:

```
// page.tsx
'use client';

export const Page = async () => {
  const query = groq`*[_type == "university"]`;

  const data = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
}
```